# What is the difference between JMP and JMP*

Tags: gdb, elf

This code has been disassembled with GDB. It is an elf executable 32 bits for x86 target. This lines come from PLT section.

```
    0x08048320 <+0>:    jmp    *0x80497b0
    0x08048326 <+6>:    push   $0x8
    0x0804832b <+11>:   jmp    0x8048300
```

I do not understand the difference between jmp * (first instruction) and the last: jmp, without asterix...

Answer (score 3):

> I do not understand the difference

It's the same difference as the difference between:

```
int x = 42;
int p = x;
```

and

```
int *px = &...;
int q = *px;
```

The `jmp *0x80497b0` jumps to symbol whose address is stored at `0x80497b0`. The `jmp 0x8048300` jumps to `0x8048300`.

To understand what this code does, read the "The Procedure Linkage Table" (or indeed the entire post) [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/03/position-independent-code-pic-in-shared-libraries/).

Answer (score 0):

It's same as the concept of pointers in C. If ptr is a pointer, *ptr refers to the value stored at the address pointed by ptr.
Similarly 
`jmp 0x8048300` 
means jump to the memory address 0x8048300.
And 
`jmp *0x80497b0` 
means jump to the address stored at the memory location 0x80497b0.